# Call to undefined method App\Libraries\GroceryCrud::set_relation()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4, grocery-crud

Im usng codeigniter4 with grocery crud for codeigniter4

But im getting the above error when i setup the relation

```
    $crud = new GroceryCrud();
    $crud->setTable('departments'); 
    $crud->columns(['depname','dep_head','bld','flr','ext','email','comp_id']);
    $crud->set_relation('comp_id','company_login','cname');  
    $crud->displayAs('depname','Department')->displayAs('dep_head','Department Head') -> displayAs('bld','Building')->displayAs('flr','Floor')->displayAs('ext','Extension') ->displayAs('email','Department email') ->displayAs('comp_id','Company');
    $output = $crud->render();
    return $this->_exampleOutput($output);
```

Error is appearing in

```
$crud->set_relation('comp_id','company_login','cname');
```

[image: Table structure]

Please help

Answer (score -1):

Solved

```
$crud->set_relation('comp_id','company_login','cname');
```

it is:

```
$crud->setRelation('comp_id','company_login','cname');
```

Comment: This happens because you were following the documentation for the old version. New version it uses camelCase for the function names.